# Best approach of implementing a string in kite game andengine

Tags: andengine

I'm developing a chinese kite flying game,I want to attach a string to my kite.

What can be the best approach of implementing a string in andengine?

Comment: Make your string (text entity) as the child of the kite (sprite entity). => kiteEntity.attachChild(stringEntity)

Comment: I have rephrased my question  . i know about the addition of string, but i want to know about the implementation of string in andengine for a realistic visualization

Answer (score 0):

Andengine uses box2D physics. It contains a RopeJoint. Depending on your game play this may give you the sort of simulation you want. Of course getting ropes to act like kite strings and looping around each other is something you'll have to decide for yourself.

Comment: Thank you . But im not using box2d physics in my whole game .So can i have an approach avoiding physics?
Maybe a series of connected lines for a curve?

Comment: well try your approach, then post some code when/if you get stuck.